# List of OpenTSDB metrics

Tags: opentsdb

Is it possible to obtain a list of available OpenTSDB metrics (not tsuids) by HTTP api without any additional plugin? Or is is possible to find out a list of metrics by HTTP api matching any pattern (e.g. sys.cpu.* or something like that)?
What is the best way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I figured out.
Looks like it is possible to use ***/api/suggest/*** endpoint with following params:

```
{
   'type': 'metrics',
   'q': '',
   'max': <int>,
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use an otsdb CLI tool or any plugin this is the best way I know. You can check also [lookup API endpoint](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/search/lookup.html) to  get e.g. all metrics with given tags and so on.